# How to SemanticImport Multiple Excel Sheets

Tags: import, dataset, excel

I have an Excel workbook with multiple sheets that I'd like to import into a dataset each.  With `Import` I can target individual sheets by their name into a nested list.

```
firstSheet=Import[NotebookDirectory[]<>"data.xlsx",{"Sheets","SomeData"}];
secondSheet=Import[NotebookDirectory[]<>"data.xlsx",{"Sheets","SomeMoreData"}];
```

I'd like to use `SemanticImport` to import the sheets with some control over their data types.  I tried

```
firstSheet = SemanticImport[NotebookDirectory[]<>"data.xlsx", 
 {"String", "Date", "String", "Number"}]
```

This appears to return a `Dataset` with the first sheet (something odd with it not understanding the date but I think if I change the Excel format for that column it will be ok).

How do I get the second sheet? I tried:

```
SemanticImport[{NotebookDirectory[]<>"data.xlsx", {"Sheets", "SomeMoreData"}}, 
 {"String", "Date", "String", "Number"}]
```

It does not like this.  Is my only option to:

1. Do the two `Imports`
2. Make a function with `Association` to format the lists as a lists of associations
3. Pass the association lists to `Dataset` to create the datasets

Also, is there a way to get all the sheets (with either `Import` or `SemanticImport`) by only opening the file once. Something along the lines of:

```
{firstSheet, secondSheet} = Import[NotebookDirectory[]<>"data.xlsx", "XLSX"]
```

but where it gives datasets instead of lists.  I tried:

```
{firstSheet, secondSheet} = 
 SemanticImport[NotebookDirectory[]<>"data.xlsx", 
  {"String", "Date", "String", "Number"}]
```

Well, I should be able to do this myself once I find out how to get `SemanticImport` to give up the other sheets.

Thanks,

Edmund

## **Update:**

With @PatoCriollo usage of `Set`, `Evaluate`, and `Symbol` (and some further research in the mean time) I've gotten closer to what I'd like to do using `Dataset`.  It still does not use SemanticImport but it does let me get an arbitrary number of sheets with different header rows into datasets.

```
dataFile = NotebookDirectory[] <> "\\data.xlsx";
sheetList = {"someData", "someMoreData"};
data = Import[dataFile, {"Sheets", sheetList}];
Set[Evaluate[Symbol[#] & /@ sheetList],
 Table[
  Dataset[Association /@
   Table[
    First[data[[sheet]]][[col]] -> Rest[data[[sheet]]][[row, col]], 
    {row, Length[Rest[data[[sheet]]]]},
    {col, Length[First[data[[sheet]]]]}
  ]],
 {sheet, Length[sheetList]}]
];

someData (*is now a Dataset of sheet someData with headers from 1st row*)
someMoreDate (*is now a Dataset of sheet someMoreData with headers from 1st row*)
```

Comment: Had wrong title from previous question. Updated title.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't think `SemanticImport` has been designed to deal with multiple Excel sheets. I work around this problem using `Import` to get the number of sheets and their names, and to import them and `ExportString` to export them as "TSV" which, on its turn, can be imported by `SemanticImportString`. An intermediate conversion of `DateObject`/`TimeObject` to `DateString` is necessary, because this data type is not handled well.

My test file:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
fileName =  FileNameJoin[{"C:", "Users", "Sjoerd", "Desktop", "test.xlsx"}];

sheets = Import[fileName, "Sheets"];

# -> SemanticImportString[
       ExportString[
         Import[fileName, {"Sheets", #}] 
            /. x : DateObject[__] :>  DateString[x, {"Year", "-", "Month", "-", "Day"}], 
         "TSV"], 
         HeaderLines -> 0
       ] & /@ sheets // Association // Dataset
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Very concise. I like how you get one Dataset with all the sheets layered in it. Not up on were and when of delayed rule yet.  I'll need to look at that some more. Thanks.

Comment: sorry but I'm not completely understanding what is going on after the import. It seems that you are saying that for all entries pattern match them into `DateObject`. I don't understand how this is working? Is this doing the same thing as `/.x:__?DateObjectQ` which pattern matches anything that is a DateObject (I think). If so, what order are things happening in the replace all?  Thanks.

Comment: @edmund `x:DateObject[__]` just means anything with Head DateObject which we will name x (could also have been written as `x__DateObject`). Import generates such DateObjects for Excel date fields, and the following Export doesn't handle that in such a way that in can be easily be imported again.

Comment: Ah, so you are pattern matching all `DateObject` functions in the `InputForm` output.  I didn't realise you could do that. So it is first naming pattern `DateObject[__]` as `x`. Then when it finds this pattern it replaces it with the `DateString` statement with the `x` symbol in it.  Then (after that replacement) does another replacement to change `x` to what it found for the pattern of `DateObject[__]`. Giving the desired result of reformatting the dates.  Ok.  One more question: Is `x : _?DateObjectQ :>` equivalent to `x : DateObject[__] :>` ?  Is one faster than the other? Thanks.

Comment: @Edmund They are functionally equivalent. `?` is `PatternTest` and performs the test that follows it on the matched (!) pattern that precedes it. I would expect the test `DateObjectQ` to be somewhat slower in this case, but I might be mistaken.

Comment: @Edmund I just timed it and it doesn't seem there is really much of a difference.

Comment: Ah, I see. So the `_?DateObjectQ` version matches every _atom_ and then checks if it is of type 'DateObject`. While the `DateObject[__]` version checks every _atom_ for a `DateObject` header before accepting it as a match. So if I had a nested list of `{{2003,12,4},{2014,1,10}}` then then the `DateObject[__]` version would find no matches since they both have header `List`.  However, the `_?DateObjectQ` would find matches because it would test if each could be converted into `DateObject`.

Comment: Nope. That doesn't work. `{{2003,12,4},{2014,1,10}}/.x:_?DateObjectQ->t`

Comment: `ReplaceAll` (`/.`) looks at every part of the expression, not only the outermost part.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
sheets = Import["sample.xlsx", "Sheets"]
(*{"DataSet1", "DataSet2"}*)

data = Import["sample.xlsx", "Data"]
(*{{{"Country", "Value"}, {"AR", 10.}, {"BE", 20.}, {"SG", 30.}, {"TW", 
   40.}}, {{"City", "Value", "Color"}, {"Amsterdam", 10., 
   "Blue"}, {"London", 20., "Red"}, {"Paris", 30., "Yellow"}}}*)

Set[Evaluate[Symbol[#] & /@ sheets], data];
DataSet1
(*{{"Country", "Value"}, {"AR", 10.}, {"BE", 20.}, {"SG", 30.}, {"TW", 
  40.}}*)
DataSet2
(*{{"City", "Value", "Color"}, {"Amsterdam", 10., "Blue"}, {"London", 
  20., "Red"}, {"Paris", 30., "Yellow"}}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a problem that may arise often. I have read your update. If someone is interested in Importing an arbitrary number of Excel worksheets, each one having a relational table of data with a header-body, and transforming them into Datasets, then the following solution is just 5 lines of code, it can read any worksheet name, and it is easy to follow ;-)

```
sheets    = Import["sample.xlsx", "Sheets"] ;

headerSet = (#[[1]] &) /@ sheets;
bodySet   = (#[[2 ;;]] &) /@ sheets;

rel2ds[header_, body_]:=Dataset[AssociationThread[header, #] & /@ body];

MapThread[rel2ds[#1,#2]&,{headerSet, bodySet}
```

Comment: Solution posted by @Zviovich is clever indeed but one may run into problems when a worksheet has names that do not follow Symbol naming conventions e.g. wages-2015